# Ansible linefile insertafter duplicate lines

Tags: ansible, idempotent

I want to fix broken sendfile support in VBox, so I need to put line  in .
I want to do that with ansible playbook. Specific task look like:

```
- name: fix broken sendfile support in VBox
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
    regexp: '^ServerAdmin'
    insertafter: 'ServerAdmin'
    line: 'EnableSendfile off'
    state: present
```

Problem is hapening when I need to call playbook again, and this task duplicate line . How to fix that.

Comment: This is a specific example of why idempotent operations are critical. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/glossary.html#idempotency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task will on the first run replace `ServerAdmin` with `EnableSendfile off` and on subsequent runs it will (since there is no `ServerAdmin` to replace) add `EnableSendfile` off to the bottom.
Since `regexp` is [pattern to replace if found](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html), you can try putting `EnableSendfile off` there:

```
- name: fix broken sendfile support in VBox
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
    regexp: 'EnableSendfile off'
    insertafter: 'ServerAdmin'
    line: 'EnableSendfile off'
    state: present
```